# How to use freetype and harfbuzz for a Qt project on Windows?

Tags: qt

For building [this sample](https://github.com/khaledhosny/QtHarfBuzzExample) on Windows, the [.pro file](https://github.com/khaledhosny/QtHarfBuzzExample/blob/master/QtHarfBuzzExample.pro#L10) saying harfbuzz, freetype2 is needed. I know these are available on qtbase on third_party but seems are not exposed for Qt projects. So how I should use or install these dependencies on Windows or use them from qtbase third party if is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not work with `pkgconfig` even do not know Qt has support it or not;
On my opinion the best way in yours case build `Harfbuzz` and `FreeType` separately from `Qt`. And then include it in project as libraries. 
Example how I make include `Boost` library in *.pro:

```
BOOST_DIR = c:/Dev/boost_1_55_0
INCLUDEPATH +=  $$quote($${BOOST_DIR}/include)
LIBS +=  \
        -L$${BOOST_DIR}/lib \
        -lboost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-d-1_55.dll \
        -lboost_system-mgw48-mt-d-1_55.dll
```

Comment: Yes, but there are some definitions to make them fit together (FT_EXPORT ... FT_CONFIG_OPTION_USE_HARFBUZZ ...  HB_DEBUG_FT ) or they won't use themself together or you will have some link issues.

Answer (score 1):

you can writer the code in *.pro to use freetype on Linux

```
LIBS += -lfreetype
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/freetype2
```

Comment: Since then I became an active contributor in HarfBuzz and yet never learnt or needed qmake  More however was looking something for Windows, thought can access Qt's HB/FT embedded ones however which now I see isn't a correct request so am upvoting your answer :)